# Integrals on $\mathbb C^2$ with a Hermitian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\mathbb C^2$ denote a two-dimensional complex Euclidean space with a Hermitian metric $h=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{2}h_{i\bar j}dz^i\otimes d\bar z^j$, where $h_{i\bar j}$ are constant numbers, then the associated fundamental form is $\omega=\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{2}\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^{2}h_{i\bar j}dz^i\wedge d\bar z^j$. Let $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4$ be four vectors in $\mathbb C^2$ which are linearly independent over $\mathbb R$, where $\omega_i=(\omega_i^1,\omega_i^2)\in \mathbb C^2$. Let $\Lambda$ be the lattice generated by $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3,\omega_4$, then we can get a complex torus $T=\mathbb C^2/\Lambda$.
Any two vectors of these four vectors determine a parallelogram in $\mathbb C^2$, for example, if we choose $\omega_1,\omega_2$, let $D_{12}$ denote the parallelogram spanned by $\omega_1,\omega_2$, then we want to compute the integral of the fundamental form $\omega$ over $D_{12}$, i.e. $\int_{D_{12}}\omega$.

According to Chern's book *Complex manifolds without potential theory. 2nd edition*. p.65 Formula 7.30, the integral may be equal to $$g_{12}=i\sum_{j,k}h_{j\bar k}(\omega^j_1\bar\omega^k_2-\omega^j_2\bar\omega^k_1)$$
(I doubt $i$ should be replaced by $\frac{i}{2}$, see the following). And according to Wells' book *Differential analysis on complex manifolds. Third edition* p.221. the period of $\omega$ over the 2-cycle is given by $$\int_{D_{12}}\omega=\frac{i}{2}\sum_{j,k}h_{j\bar k}(\omega^j_1\bar\omega^k_2-\omega^j_2\bar\omega^k_1).$$

Here my question is: why the integral $\omega$ over the parallelogram $D_{12}$ takes such form? And does it relate to $\omega(u,v),u,v\in T_{\mathbb C^2}$?

Comment: Do we really *have* to use $\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots$ for vectors when we're using $\omega$ for the associated $(1,1)$-form?

Comment: Yes, integrating a $2$-form $\omega$ over the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$ should be given by $\omega(u,v)$ ... Parametrize by $s,t$, pull back, and you get $\int_0^1\int_0^1\omega(su,tv)\,ds\,dt$. How does this work out? ... That said, the factor of $1/2$ in the associated $(1,1)$-form is there to make $dz\wedge d\bar z$ turn into $dx\wedge dy$. I am not sure why Chern dropped the $1/2$.

Comment: @TedShifrin, can you elaborate a bit on why integrating 2-form $\omega$ over the parallelogram spanned by $u$ and $v$ is given by $\omega(u,v)$? For example, if we choose two vectors $(1,0),(0,i)\in \mathbb C^2$, then, what is the corresponding vectors $u$ and $v$? and why do we take conjugation on the second factor?

Comment: @TedShifrin, does it work for arbitrary $2$-form? For example, if we take $\omega=xdx\wedge dy$, $u=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, $v=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, then the integral is $\int_0^1\int_0^1xdxdy=\frac{1}{2}$, while $\omega(u,v)=x$, does it provide a counter-example?

Comment: No, no. I was sloppy. Of course we're talking about a constant $2$-form. You need a $(1,1)$-form to get the induced area $2$-form on a complex subspace. As I suggested before, parametrize the parallelogram explicitly, pull back the $2$-form as always, and integrate.